# VBA: Fluctuating tables, how to change value in table 127, column 3, depending table 126, column 3?

Tags: vba

I need some help - once again. :)

I have 2 fluctuating tables, where the number of rows can change from 1 (minimum) to xx (in theory to infinity), depending on the users choice with the buttons add "Tilføj anlæg" and remove "Fjern anlæg". But the 2 tables will always have the same amount of rows. And in both tables, the value can be chosen from a drop-down list in each column, as shown on attached picture

**The task:**
Second table (127), column (3), should copy, without locking, the value of the first table (126), column (3).
However (and here is the tricky part for me), it should be the same row-number at any amount of rows. And the numbers in attached picture one are not locked as shown in picture to. So in can't work work with a reference to column (2).

Hope that you can help me out.
And please feel free to ask if something doesn't add up.

Kind regards
Johan B-S
CPH, Denmark.

**My initial code, which doesn't work:**

```
If Not Intersect(Target, _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BEREGNING").Range("Tabel26").Columns(3)) Is Nothing _
    And Target.Columns.Count = 1 _
    And Target.Rows.Count = 1 Then
    'Target.Columns.Count=1 + Target.Rows.Count=1 guarantees that just a single cell has changed'
    If Target.Value = "Indendørs" Then
          If Not Intersect(Target, _
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BEREGNING").Range("Tabel26").Columns(3)) Is Nothing _
          And Target.Columns.Count = 1 _
          And Target.Rows.Count = 1 Then
          Target.Value = "Indendørs"
          Else
          End If
     Else
     End If
End If
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work with both single and multiple cells.

```
Dim TopRow127 As Long, LeftCol127 As Long
Dim RowOffset As Long, ColOffset As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim rTopLeftCell_126 As Range
Dim c As Variant

Set r = Intersect(Range("Table127"), Target)
Set rTopLeftCell_126 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BEREGNING").Range("Tabel26")(1) ' topleft cell of target table

TopRow127 = Range("Table127").Row       ' topleft coordinates of source table
LeftCol127 = Range("Table127").Column

For Each c In r
    RowOffset = c.Row - TopRow127
    ColOffset = c.Column - LeftCol127
    
    rTopLeftCell_126.Offset(RowOffset, ColOffset) = c
Next c
```

(You'll still need to add some controls to avoid unexpected behaviour on 0, negative and Nothing values.)

Comment: Hi AcsErno.
Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately this didn't work. It even stopped some of my other VBA codes. 

Do you have another idea, that copies the value from table 126 to 127, cell by cell and row by row?
I'm stuck at this moment. - and surely because I'm still a newbie LOL...

Comment: Put my code into a `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` sub in the module sheet behind the sheet with `Table127`. This should fire all the times when the user changes anything on the sheet. Set a breakpoint to the first code line (Intersect), run it step by step and understand what happens.

Comment: Hi AczErno.

I've tried and tried. But unfortunately its doesn't work.
Ive using med worksheet_change (ByVal Target As Range). And in a new worksheet_change. 
I've even added a bit. 
But stil doesn't do the job.

Not sure whether I'm describing enough or correctly.
So here's my present code (that doesn't work):

Comment: Dim TopRow127 As Long, LeftCol127 As Long
Dim RowOffset As Long, ColOffset As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim rTopLeftCell_126 As Range
Dim c As Variant
Dim Target As Range
Set Target = ActiveCell
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler
Set r = Intersect(Range("Table127"), Target)
Set rTopLeftCell_126 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BEREGNING").Range("Tabel26")(1)
TopRow127 = Range("Table127").Row
LeftCol127 = Range("Table127").Column
For Each c In r
RowOffset = c.Row - TopRow127
ColOffset = c.Column - LeftCol127
rTopLeftCell_126.Offset(RowOffset, ColOffset) = c
Next c

Comment: How doesn't it work? Does it even fire the routine?

Comment: Hi again, and thank you for the help.
No it doesn't. Neither when using "_Change2 ()" or "_Change1 (ByVal Target As Range).
The code even blocks the action of other codes. I have a lot of VBA codes that changes values in certain cells depending on other cells. But these are all in the same table.
My issue is to copy the value from a certain cell in one row from one table to a certain cell in another table.

Thank you once again.
Regards JBS